# DBX error in Delphi XE3, when connecting to a SQL Server database

Tags: delphi, dbx, delphi-xe3

When I try to connect to a MS SQL Server database using DBX an error pops up saying that the driver is not properly installed, or missing. I tried with ADO driver and it worked like charm, but the thing is that I need DBX driver to work because I want to modify an app that has been developed with DBX technology.

I reinstalled Delphi XE3, and also asked a friend of mine to test it and the error is the same. Does somebody has any ideea on how to solve it ?

The exactly message was this:

> Borland.Data.TDBXError: DBX Error:  Driver could not be properly
>   initialized.  Client library may be missing, not installed properly,
>   of the wrong version, or the driver may be missing from the system
>   path.

I must mention that I tried it on a local instance of MSSQL Server 2012 and on a remote MSSQL Server 2008 instance. My OS win8 x64;

Best regards,

Comment: What SKU (Professional, Ultimate, etc.) of Delphi do you have installed? The SQL Server drivers are only available in the higher ones, so if you have Standard or Pro you're out of luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the wrong version of the SQL Native Client installed on your system. DBX will only work with V10, while you probably have V11 installed. Try to install the V10 version of the client.

Comment: That was the solution. Thank you very much.